# get schema name as a user input and use it in a cursor

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, cursor, sqlplus

I want to get the user input to a variable and use it to a cursor. This user input says which database to use.

```
--source source 
source varchar2(100) := &SOURCE_ATS_USER_SCHEMA;
CURSOR cur_list is
    select ID from source.WEB_FE;
```

I use above code with in DECLARE block. When this runs, a prompt asks the user input.
Let's say I input as "ONE", then it gives the error "identifier ONE must be declared" and though ONE.WEB_FE table exist it says "table or view does not exist".

So how to get schema name as a user input and use it in a cursor?

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems here. The `identifier ONE must be declared` message is because you haven't quoted the substitution variable. If you have `set verify on` then you'll see something like:

```
Enter value for source_ats_user_schema: ONE
old   2: source varchar2(100) := &SOURCE_ATS_USER_SCHEMA;
new   2: source varchar2(100) := ONE;
source varchar2(100) := ONE;
                        *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 25:
PLS-00201: identifier 'SCOTT' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 8:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
```

The `*`'d position shows that it doesn't know what `ONE` means. Since you want it to be treated as a string here, you'd need to do:

```
source varchar2(100) := '&SOURCE_ATS_USER_SCHEMA';
```

... which would show:

```
Enter value for source_ats_user_schema: ONE
old   2: source varchar2(100) := '&SOURCE_ATS_USER_SCHEMA';
new   2: source varchar2(100) := 'ONE';
```

...which is valid. As far as it goes; this doesn't actually help you because you still have the second error:

```
    select ID from source.WEB_FE;
                          *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-06550: line 4, column 27:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06550: line 4, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Notice that the error is referring to `source.WEB_FE`, *not* `ONE.WEB_FE`. `source` is not being substituted. Generally you'd need to use one of the methods @NicholasKrasnov shows in his answer, but you're actually making this more complicated than it needs to be; in this specific case you don't need to declare `source` at all, you can just do:

```
CURSOR cur_list is
    select ID from &SOURCE_ATS_USER_SCHEMA..WEB_FE;
```

Note that contrary to what I just said, here you do not need to quote the substitution variable, but you do need to explicitly terminate it with a `.`, to stop it treating the real `.` before the table name as a terminator. (Try it without the extra `.` to see what happens if you don't).

When you run it it will prompt and the verify output will look like:

```
Enter value for source_ats_user_schema: ONE
old   3:     select ID from &SOURCE_ATS_USER_SCHEMA..WEB_FE;
new   3:     select ID from ONE.WEB_FE;
```

As you can see, it is now looking for the the table in the schema you specified. This is still dynamic, but in a special SQL*Plus way.

With any of these methods though, you need to consider the potential for SQL injection.

Comment: Thank you. source varchar2(100) := '&SOURCE_ATS_USER_SCHEMA'; did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `select on` privilege to query tables you do not own. To be able to change schema qualifier in `from` clause of a query you need to use dynamic SQL. For example:

```
HR@XE> edit
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  declare
  2   c sys_refcursor;
  3   l_emp_name varchar2(11);
  4  begin
  5    open c for 'select first_name from ' || '&schema_name' || '.employees where rownum <= 10';
  6    loop
  7      fetch c into l_emp_name;
  8      exit when c%notfound;
  9      dbms_output.put_line(l_emp_name);
 10    end loop;
 11    close c;
 12* end;
HR@XE> /
Enter value for schema_name: hr
old   5:   open c for 'select first_name from ' || '&schema_name' || '.employees where rownum <= 10';
new   5:   open c for 'select first_name from ' || 'hr' || '.employees where rownum <= 10';

Ellen
Sundar
Mozhe
David
Hermann
Shelli
Amit
Elizabeth
Sarah
David

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

HR@XE>
```

Also you can keep using static SQL and change schema by issuing

```
alter session set current_schema = <<schema_name>>;
```

Note in this case you do not need to qualify a table you are querying by specifying a schema name. For example. The `employee` table exists in both schemas `HR` and `NK` but contains different data:

```
HR@XE> select user from dual;

USER
------------------------------
HR

HR@XE> declare
  2    cursor c is
  3      select first_name
  4        from employees
  5       where rownum <= 7;
  6    l_emp_name varchar2(11);
  7  begin
  8     open c;
  9     loop
 10       fetch c into l_emp_name;
 11       exit when c%notfound;
 12       dbms_output.put_line(l_emp_name);
 13     end loop;
 14     close c;
 15  end;
 16  /

Ellen
Sundar
Mozhe
David
Hermann
Shelli
Amit

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

HR@XE> alter session set current_schema=NK;

Session altered.

HR@XE> declare
  2    cursor c is
  3      select first_name
  4        from employees
  5       where rownum <= 7;
  6    l_emp_name varchar2(11);
  7  begin
  8     open c;
  9     loop
 10       fetch c into l_emp_name;
 11       exit when c%notfound;
 12       dbms_output.put_line(l_emp_name);
 13     end loop;
 14     close c;
 15  end;
 16  /

Tom

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

HR@XE> alter session set current_schema=HR;

Session altered.

HR@XE>
```

Comment: Thank you for the support. But I had to refer four tables from a different schema and I could not prompt user to enter same for four times. As Alex Poole mentioned, source varchar2(100) := '&SOURCE_ATS_USER_SCHEMA'; worked for me.